# MQ 7.5 + Glassfish 4 Integration

Tags: ibm-mq, glassfish-4

I am trying to setup IBM MQ 7.5.0.2 + Glassfish 4(Payara) JDK 8 and using Camel Integration as a Client
I have followed deploying RAR approach however I am unable to make a connection from Glassfish to MQ
The Connection Pool ping fails stating "Ping Connection Pool failed for MyPool. MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 Please check the server.log for more details."

In server logs, I see the below:

```
[#|2017-03-24T08:40:31.494+1100|WARNING|Payara 4.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator|_ThreadID=111;_ThreadName=org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1;_TimeMillis=1490305231494;_LevelValue=900;|RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool MyPool. Exception : com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.|#]

RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ MyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011|#]
```

I am following the below:
https://genericjmsra.java.net/docs/websphere-mq-integration-guide/webspheremq_integration_guide.html

Comment: What does the linked exception say?

Comment: I dont see any linked Exception I was able to solve the Ping Issue the problem was that Authentication Issue with the QueueManager 
Adding the Payara User in the mqm group I was able to connect.

Do you know on what port does Glassfish connect with IBM MQ, is it 7676 the JMS Port ? as I am unable to connect with this port, I am using JMSToolBox to view the Messages do you know any other way to check?

Comment: I don't know what Glassfish might choose to use by default, but it needs to use the same port number that the listener running at the queue manager is listening on. I have not head of 7676 being a port number associated with MQ. 1414 is the default one, but you are well advised to choose your own one.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, the issue in my case was that the channel was blocked by the CHLAUTH rule. I fixed the issue by disabling authorisation on the channel using the below commands on the IBM Integration Console:

alter QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED) alter AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS) AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) CHCKCLNT(none) REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)